# "How to reference" link in "Copied content" edit rejection reason is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing, tag-wiki

Pretty self explanatory.

[image: Broken link in reject reason]

Comment: What does that link try to point to now?

Comment: @Unionhawk Based on the screenshot, nothing. It looks like the syntax to create the link is invalid somewhere. Possibly an extra space in the URL, or extra slashes.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it would help if I looked more closely and saw it was a markdown break not a https break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just want to say that it's fixed now.